# Azure Web Job Run Command Incorrectly Set

Tags: visual-studio, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service

I have an azure website running as an App Service which I publish to Azure from Visual Studio.  I have multiple webjobs which are all linked to the main web project.

When I add a new webjob it fails because the wrong RUN COMMAND is attached to it.  For instance, the webjob QuarterHrsWebJob fails because it has somehow been set up with a Run command of "doctap.exe".  doctap.exe is the exe belonging to a different webjob (called doctap) - but somehow it has been assigned to QuarterHrsWebJob as well.

See screenshot showing "Run command: doctap.exe" for the QueryHrsWebJob.

Many thanks for your help.

[image: run command shows as doctap.exe instead of QuarterHrsWebJob]

[image: list of all web jobs]

Comment: Try looking at your files using Kudu Console, and make sure there is no `doctap.exe` under `d:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\continuous\QueryHrsWebJob`

Comment: Many thanks David - that was the problem.  I deleted it and it works fine now.  But whenever I republish from visual studio it copies the doctap.exe file into d:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\continuous\QueryHrsWebJob (as well as also correctly copying it into d:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\continuous\doctap).  Is there a way of stopping it doing this every time I publish so I don't have to delete it every time? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a project reference to the project containing doctab.exe from the QueryHrsWebJob? I was able to reproduce the problem you are seeing by creating a similar reference between two Web Jobs.

If you do not have a reference like this, could you please share the project file for both affected Web Jobs and your webjob-publish-settings.json files?

Comment: Thanks Phil - you were right - I was indirectly referencing the doctap project from the QueryHrsWebJob project.  I've removed the reference and all working perfectly.  Thank you so much for your help :)